# How to query inventory qty per day for the last week

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that pulls the inventory for each day, for the trailing 7 days (a week). Here is the query:

```
select id, day, inventory
from tbl
where day >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Produces this table:

```
id      day         inventory
1223    2019-05-01  1
1223    2019-05-02  5
412345  2019-05-02  3
412345  2019-05-03  1
12      2019-05-02  8
1234    2019-05-01  467
1234    2019-05-02  493
```

I am unsure what the easiest way to get the following results:

```
id      2019-05-01  2019-05-02  2019-05-03
1223    1           5
412345              3           1
12                  8
1234    467         493
```

Comment: Oracle Database

Comment: Thanks Ke'ene Raynor.  Is this a one-time query (where dates can be hard-coded), or do you need this to dynamically look back a week from an arbitrary date?  Thanks

Comment: Dynamic. Apologies for not being specific, I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Thanks Ke'ene Raynor.  Is it a requirement that the column headers are date literals ID, 2019-05-01, 2019-05-02 etc?  Is it acceptable if the result comes back with headers of ID, DAY_1, DAY_2 (or whatever) representing the seven previous days?

Comment: They can be anything. Day_1, Day_2 is fine I will probably change them depending when I run the query. Ex. Wedneday, Thursday...

Answer (score 0):

As it is not a requirement to have specific column-names in the return, one approach to this kind of thing is a `PIVOT`.
`PIVOT` can be strict about having static buckets, so the example here uses dynamic sql to move the 7-day window around.
This kind of approach has some real downsides -- dynamic sql, compiled objects, kludgy code, etc. so I hesitate to actually recommend this kind of approach, but using dynamic sql allows for providing static buckets to `PIVOT`.
Below is an example, using the table you provided.

This example will sum all the inventory per `ID`, for each day, for a seven-day period starting with the provided date.  (Defaulting to the seven days before today (exclusive of today)).

To allow this to be called from SQL, this example creates some data-transfer objects and a function to create and return them for the 7-day window.

Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (ID INTEGER, DAY DATE, INVENTORY INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1223, DATE '2019-05-01', 1);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1223, DATE '2019-05-02', 5);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (412345, DATE '2019-05-02', 3);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (412345, DATE '2019-05-03', 1);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (12, DATE '2019-05-02', 8);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1234, DATE '2019-05-01', 467);
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES (1234, DATE '2019-05-02', 493);
COMMIT;
```

Objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE WEEK_INVENTORY IS OBJECT
(ID INTEGER, DAY_1 INTEGER, DAY_2 INTEGER, DAY_3 INTEGER, DAY_4 INTEGER, DAY_5 INTEGER, DAY_6 INTEGER, DAY_7 INTEGER);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE WEEK_INVENTORIES IS TABLE OF WEEK_INVENTORY;
/

Type created.
Type created.
```

And the function.  The input `DATE` is the start of the seven-day window.  The function does a dynamic pivot, totalling the inventory for each `ID`, for each day in the seven-day-window.  For this example, all dates are truncated (I'm not sure whether the actual data would require this).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SEVEN_DAYS_OF_INVENTORY(P_START_DATE IN DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE - 7) RETURN WEEK_INVENTORIES
IS
V_BUCKETS_CLAUSE CHARACTER VARYING(256);
V_WEEK_INVENTORIES WEEK_INVENTORIES := WEEK_INVENTORIES();
BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG('DATE '''||TO_CHAR(P_START_DATE + (LEVEL - 1),'YYYY-MM-DD')||''' AS DAY_'||LEVEL,',')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NULL)
        INTO V_BUCKETS_CLAUSE
    FROM  DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('SELECT WEEK_INVENTORY(ID, DAY_1, DAY_2, DAY_3, DAY_4, DAY_5, DAY_6, DAY_7) FROM
(SELECT ID, INVENTORY, TRUNC(DAY) AS TRUNC_DAY FROM TBL)
PIVOT (SUM(INVENTORY) FOR TRUNC_DAY IN (%s))
ORDER BY ID ASC',V_BUCKETS_CLAUSE) BULK COLLECT INTO V_WEEK_INVENTORIES;
RETURN V_WEEK_INVENTORIES;
END;
/

Function created.
```

Then test it:

Default (Today is May 7, 2019, so it starts with April 30, 2019):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SEVEN_DAYS_OF_INVENTORY());
```

Result:

```
       ID    DAY_1    DAY_2    DAY_3    DAY_4    DAY_5    DAY_6    DAY_7
_________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________
       12                          8
     1223                 1        5
     1234               467      493
   412345                          3        1
```

Then move it forward one day (May 1 2019 - May 7 2019):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SEVEN_DAYS_OF_INVENTORY(SYSDATE - 6));
```

Result:

```
       ID    DAY_1    DAY_2    DAY_3    DAY_4    DAY_5    DAY_6    DAY_7
_________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________
       12                 8
     1223        1        5
     1234      467      493
   412345                 3        1
```

Or two days ( May 2, 2019 - May 8, 2019):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SEVEN_DAYS_OF_INVENTORY(DATE '2019-05-02'));
```

Result:

```
       ID    DAY_1    DAY_2    DAY_3    DAY_4    DAY_5    DAY_6    DAY_7
_________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________ ________
       12        8
     1223        5
     1234      493
   412345        3        1
```